# ProcessMaker 3.1.3-community: unit and functional tests

Tags: php, bpmn, processmaker

do you have any experiences about writing unit/functional tests for ProcessMaker.
I made research and:

1. Classes, which can have auto-generated test class is only from "workflow/engine/classes" folder.
2. There is missing "test" folder and "test/bootstrap/unit.php" file.
3. When I managed above problems, I can't write tests for newly created plugin...?

Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about the unit tests in the core, if you only want to run unit tests on your own plugin.

This requires phpunit. Then, you just need 2 main files really.

phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         codecoverage="true"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="true"
         bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="My Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/MyTestFolder/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <php>
        <const name="ROOT_FOLDER" value="processmaker" />
        <const name="PLUGIN_NAME" value="MyPluginName" />
        <const name="SYS_SYS" value="workflow" />
        <const name="SYS_SKIN" value="neoclassic" />
        <const name="SYS_LANG" value="en" />
    </php> 
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="tests/reports/coverage" lowUpperBound="80" highLowerBound="90"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="tests/reports/coverage.xml"/>
        <log type="coverage-php" target="tests/reports/coverage.serialized"/>
        <log type="coverage-text" target="php://stdout" showUncoveredFiles="false"/>
        <log type="junit" target="tests/reports/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>

</phpunit>
```

And then the bootstrap.php that is being referenced

```
<?php
if ( !defined('PATH_SEP') ) {
    define("PATH_SEP", (substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) == "WIN")? "\\" : "/");
}

//Important: Make sure that you change the realpath to reflect your environment
//Configure PATH_TRUNK to the base directory that contains the "workflow/engine/plugins" directory
define('PATH_TRUNK', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../../..') . PATH_SEP);
define('PATH_HOME',  PATH_TRUNK . 'workflow' . PATH_SEP);

require_once (PATH_TRUNK . "framework/src/Maveriks/Util/ClassLoader.php");
require_once (PATH_HOME . 'engine' . PATH_SEP . 'config' . PATH_SEP . 'paths_installed.php');
require_once (PATH_HOME . 'engine' . PATH_SEP . 'config' . PATH_SEP . 'paths.php');
require_once (PATH_CORE . 'classes' . PATH_SEP . 'class.system.php');
require_once ( "propel/Propel.php" );
require_once ( "creole/Creole.php" );
require_once(PATH_DB . SYS_SYS . PATH_SEP . "db.php");

//***************** PM Paths DATA **************************
define('PATH_DATA_SITE',                PATH_DATA      . 'sites/' . SYS_SYS . '/');
define('PATH_DOCUMENT',                 PATH_DATA_SITE . 'files/');
define('PATH_DATA_MAILTEMPLATES',       PATH_DATA_SITE . 'mailTemplates/');
define('PATH_DATA_PUBLIC',              PATH_DATA_SITE . 'public/');
define('PATH_DATA_REPORTS',             PATH_DATA_SITE . 'reports/');
define('PATH_DYNAFORM',                 PATH_DATA_SITE . 'xmlForms/');
define('PATH_IMAGES_ENVIRONMENT_FILES', PATH_DATA_SITE . 'usersFiles' . PATH_SEP);
define('PATH_IMAGES_ENVIRONMENT_USERS', PATH_DATA_SITE . 'usersPhotographies' . PATH_SEP);

G::LoadClass ( 'system' );

$config = System::getSystemConfiguration();

$error_level  = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT;

ini_set('display_errors', $error_level);
ini_set('error_reporting', $error_level);
ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');
ini_set('default_charset', "UTF-8");
ini_set('memory_limit', $config['memory_limit']);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', $config['wsdl_cache']);
ini_set('date.timezone', $config['time_zone']);

define ('DEBUG_SQL_LOG', $config['debug_sql']);
define ('DEBUG_TIME_LOG', $config['debug_time']);
define ('DEBUG_CALENDAR_LOG', $config['debug_calendar']);
define ('MEMCACHED_ENABLED',  $config['memcached']);
define ('MEMCACHED_SERVER',   $config['memcached_server']);
define ('TIME_ZONE', $config['time_zone']);

$classLoader = \Maveriks\Util\ClassLoader::getInstance();
$classLoader->add(PATH_TRUNK . "framework" . PATH_SEP . "src" . PATH_SEP, "Maveriks");
$classLoader->add(PATH_CORE . "src" . PATH_SEP, "ProcessMaker");
$classLoader->add(PATH_CORE . "src" . PATH_SEP);

//Add vendors to autoloader
$classLoader->add(PATH_TRUNK . "vendor" . PATH_SEP . "luracast" . PATH_SEP . "restler" . PATH_SEP . "vendor", "Luracast");
$classLoader->add(PATH_TRUNK . "vendor" . PATH_SEP . "bshaffer" . PATH_SEP . "oauth2-server-php" . PATH_SEP . "src" . PATH_SEP, "OAuth2");
$classLoader->addClass("Bootstrap", PATH_TRUNK . "gulliver" . PATH_SEP . "system" . PATH_SEP . "class.bootstrap.php");

//$classLoader->addModelClassPath(PATH_TRUNK . "workflow" . PATH_SEP . "engine" . PATH_SEP . "classes" . PATH_SEP . "model" . PATH_SEP);

//Load classes
G::LoadThirdParty('pear/json','class.json');
G::LoadThirdParty('smarty/libs','Smarty.class');
G::LoadSystem('error');
G::LoadSystem('dbconnection');
G::LoadSystem('dbsession');
G::LoadSystem('dbrecordset');
G::LoadSystem('dbtable');
G::LoadSystem('rbac' );
G::LoadSystem('publisher');
G::LoadSystem('templatePower');
G::LoadSystem('xmlDocument');
G::LoadSystem('xmlform');
G::LoadSystem('xmlformExtension');
G::LoadSystem('form');
G::LoadSystem('menu');
G::LoadSystem("xmlMenu");
G::LoadSystem('dvEditor');
G::LoadSystem('table');
G::LoadSystem('pagedTable');

//require_once (PATH_GULLIVER . PATH_SEP . 'class.bootstrap.php');
//define( 'PATH_GULLIVER_HOME', PATH_TRUNK . 'gulliver' . PATH_SEP );

spl_autoload_register(array('Bootstrap', 'autoloadClass'));

//DATABASE propel classes used in 'Cases' Options
Bootstrap::registerClass('Entity_Base',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/entities/Base.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseContent',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseContent.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Content',            PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Content.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseContentPeer',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseContentPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('ContentPeer',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/ContentPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseApplication',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseApplication.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('ApplicationPeer',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/ApplicationPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Application',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Application.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppDelegation',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppDelegation.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseHoliday',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseHoliday.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseHolidayPeer',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseHolidayPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseTask',           PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseTask.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseTaskPeer',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseTaskPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('HolidayPeer',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/HolidayPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Holiday',            PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Holiday.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Task',               PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Task.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('TaskPeer',           PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/TaskPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('dates',              PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/class.dates.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('calendar',           PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/class.calendar.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppDelegation',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppDelegation.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppDelegationPeer',PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppDelegationPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppDelegationPeer',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppDelegationPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppDelay',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppDelay.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppDelayPeer',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppDelayPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppDelay',           PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppDelay.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAdditionalTables',PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAdditionalTables.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AdditionalTables',   PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AdditionalTables.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppCacheView',   PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppCacheView.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppCacheView',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppCacheView.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppCacheViewPeer',PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppCacheViewPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppCacheViewPeer',   PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppCacheViewPeer.php");

/*----------------------------------********---------------------------------*/
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppTimeoutActionExecuted',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppTimeoutActionExecuted.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppTimeoutActionExecuted',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppTimeoutActionExecuted.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppTimeoutActionExecutedPeer',PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppTimeoutActionExecutedPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppTimeoutActionExecutedPeer',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppTimeoutActionExecutedPeer.php");
/*----------------------------------********---------------------------------*/

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseInputDocument',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseInputDocument.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('InputDocument',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/InputDocument.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppDocument',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppDocument.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppDocument',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppDocument.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppDocumentPeer',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppDocumentPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppEvent',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppEvent.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppEvent',           PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppEvent.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppEventPeer',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppEventPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppHistory',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppHistory.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppHistory',         PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppHistory.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppHistoryPeer',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppHistoryPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppFolder',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppFolder.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppFolder',          PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppFolder.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppFolderPeer',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppFolderPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppMessage',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppMessage.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppMessage',         PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppMessage.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppMessagePeer', PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppMessagePeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppMessagePeer',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppMessagePeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppNotesPeer',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppNotesPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppNotesPeer',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppNotesPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppNotes',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppNotes.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppNotes',            PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppNotes.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppOwner',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppOwner.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppOwner',            PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppOwner.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppOwnerPeer',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppOwnerPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppSolrQueue',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppSolrQueue.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Entity_AppSolrQueue', PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/entities/AppSolrQueue.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppSolrQueue',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppSolrQueue.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppSolrQueuePeer',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppSolrQueuePeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseAppThread',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseAppThread.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppThread',           PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppThread.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('AppThreadPeer',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/AppThreadPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseCaseScheduler',   PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseCaseScheduler.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('CaseScheduler',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/CaseScheduler.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseCaseSchedulerPeer',PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseCaseSchedulerPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('CaseSchedulerPeer',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/CaseSchedulerPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseCaseTracker',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseCaseTracker.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('CaseTracker',         PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/CaseTracker.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseCaseTrackerPeer', PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseCaseTrackerPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('CaseTrackerPeer',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/CaseTrackerPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseCaseTrackerObject',PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseCaseTrackerObject.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('CaseTrackerObject',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/CaseTrackerObject.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseCaseTrackerObjectPeer',PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseCaseTrackerObjectPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('CaseTrackerObjectPeer',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/CaseTrackerObjectPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseDbSource',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseDbSource.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('DbSource',            PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/DbSource.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('XMLDB',              PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/class.xmlDb.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('dynaFormHandler',    PATH_GULLIVER . "class.dynaformhandler.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('DynaFormField',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/class.dynaFormField.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseDynaform',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseDynaform.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Dynaform',           PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Dynaform.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('DynaformPeer',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/DynaformPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseEvent',          PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseEvent.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Event',              PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Event.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseEventPeer',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseEventPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('EventPeer',          PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/EventPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseFields',         PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseFields.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Fields',             PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Fields.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseGateway',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseGateway.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Gateway',            PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Gateway.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseGroupUser',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseGroupUser.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Groupwf',            PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Groupwf.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('GroupUser',          PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/GroupUser.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseGroupUserPeer',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseGroupUserPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('GroupUserPeer',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/GroupUserPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseGroupwfPeer',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseGroupwfPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('GroupwfPeer',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/GroupwfPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseInputDocumentPeer',PATH_HOME . 'engine/classes/model/om/BaseInputDocumentPeer.php');
Bootstrap::registerClass('InputDocumentPeer',  PATH_HOME . 'engine/classes/model/InputDocumentPeer.php');

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseIsoCountry',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseIsoCountry.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('IsoCountry',         PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/IsoCountry.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseTranslation',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseTranslation.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Translation',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Translation.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseLanguage',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseLanguage.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseLanguagePeer',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseLanguagePeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Language',           PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Language.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseLogCasesScheduler',PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseLogCasesScheduler.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('LogCasesScheduler',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/LogCasesScheduler.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseObjectPermission',PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseObjectPermission.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('ObjectPermission',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/ObjectPermission.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('ObjectPermissionPeer',PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/ObjectPermissionPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseOutputDocument',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseOutputDocument.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('OutputDocument',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/OutputDocument.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('OutputDocumentPeer',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/OutputDocumentPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseProcess',         PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseProcess.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseProcessCategory', PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseProcessCategory.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('ProcessCategory',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/ProcessCategory.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('ProcessCategoryPeer', PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/ProcessCategoryPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('ProcessPeer',         PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/ProcessPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Process',             PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Process.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseProcessUser',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseProcessUser.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('ProcessUser',         PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/ProcessUser.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseProcessUserPeer', PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseProcessUserPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('ProcessUserPeer',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/ProcessUserPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseReportTable',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseReportTable.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('ReportTable',         PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/ReportTable.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('ReportTablePeer',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/ReportTablePeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseReportVar',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseReportVar.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('ReportVar',           PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/ReportVar.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseReportVarPeer',   PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseReportVarPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('ReportVarPeer',       PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/ReportVarPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseRoute',           PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseRoute.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Route',               PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Route.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('RoutePeer',           PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/RoutePeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseStep',            PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseStep.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Step',                PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Step.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('StepPeer',            PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/StepPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseStepSupervisor',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseStepSupervisor.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('StepSupervisor',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/StepSupervisor.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseStepSupervisorPeer',PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseStepSupervisorPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('StepSupervisorPeer',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/StepSupervisorPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseStepTrigger',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseStepTrigger.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('StepTrigger',         PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/StepTrigger.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('StepTriggerPeer',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/StepTriggerPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('SolrRequestData',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/entities/SolrRequestData.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('SolrUpdateDocument',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/entities/SolrUpdateDocument.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseSwimlanesElements',PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseSwimlanesElements.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('SwimlanesElements',   PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/SwimlanesElements.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseSwimlanesElementsPeer',PATH_HOME ."engine/classes/model/om/BaseSwimlanesElementsPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('SwimlanesElementsPeer',PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/SwimlanesElementsPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseSubApplication',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseSubApplication.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('SubApplication',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/SubApplication.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('SubApplicationPeer',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/SubApplicationPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseSubProcess',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseSubProcess.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('SubProcess',          PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/SubProcess.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseSubProcessPeer',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseSubProcessPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('SubProcessPeer',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/SubProcessPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseTask',            PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseTask.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Task',                PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Task.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseTaskUser',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseTaskUser.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('TaskUserPeer',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/TaskUserPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('TaskUser',            PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/TaskUser.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseTriggers',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseTriggers.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Triggers',            PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Triggers.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseTriggersPeer',    PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseTriggersPeer.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('TriggersPeer',        PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/TriggersPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseUsers',           PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseUsers.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('IsoCountry',          PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/IsoCountry.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseIsoSubdivision',  PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseIsoSubdivision.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('IsoSubdivision',      PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/IsoSubdivision.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('BaseIsoLocation',     PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/om/BaseIsoLocation.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('IsoLocation',         PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/IsoLocation.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('Users',               PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/Users.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass('UsersPeer',           PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/model/UsersPeer.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('Xml_Node',            PATH_GULLIVER . "class.xmlDocument.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass('wsResponse',          PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/class.wsResponse.php");

Bootstrap::registerClass("PMLicensedFeatures",  PATH_HOME . "engine" . PATH_SEP . "classes" . PATH_SEP . "class.licensedFeatures.php");
Bootstrap::registerClass("AddonsManagerPeer",   PATH_HOME . "engine" . PATH_SEP . "classes" . PATH_SEP . "model" . PATH_SEP . "AddonsManagerPeer.php");
/*----------------------------------********---------------------------------*/
Bootstrap::registerClass('dashboards',   PATH_HOME . "engine/classes/class.dashboards.php");
/*----------------------------------********---------------------------------*/

$arrayClass = array("Configuration", "EmailServer", "ListInbox", "ListParticipatedHistory");

foreach ($arrayClass as $value) {
    Bootstrap::registerClass("Base" . $value,          PATH_HOME . "engine" . PATH_SEP . "classes" . PATH_SEP . "model" . PATH_SEP . "om" . PATH_SEP . "Base" . $value . ".php");
    Bootstrap::registerClass($value,                   PATH_HOME . "engine" . PATH_SEP . "classes" . PATH_SEP . "model" . PATH_SEP . $value . ".php");
    Bootstrap::registerClass("Base" . $value . "Peer", PATH_HOME . "engine" . PATH_SEP . "classes" . PATH_SEP . "model" . PATH_SEP . "om" . PATH_SEP . "Base" . $value . "Peer.php");
    Bootstrap::registerClass($value . "Peer",          PATH_HOME . "engine" . PATH_SEP . "classes" . PATH_SEP . "model" . PATH_SEP . $value . "Peer.php");
}

G::LoadClass("serverConfiguration");
G::LoadClass("dates"); //Load Criteria
//DB

$dsn     = DB_ADAPTER . "://" . DB_USER . ":" . DB_PASS . "@" . DB_HOST . "/" . DB_NAME . '?encoding=utf8';
$dsnRbac = DB_ADAPTER . "://" . DB_RBAC_USER . ":" . DB_RBAC_PASS . "@" . DB_RBAC_HOST . "/" . DB_RBAC_NAME . '?encoding=utf8';
$dsnRp   = DB_ADAPTER . "://" . DB_REPORT_USER . ":" . DB_REPORT_PASS . "@" . DB_REPORT_HOST . "/" . DB_REPORT_NAME;

$propelConfig['datasources']['workflow']['connection'] = $dsn;
$propelConfig['datasources']['workflow']['adapter'] = DB_ADAPTER;
$propelConfig['datasources']['rbac']['connection'] = $dsnRbac;
$propelConfig['datasources']['rbac']['adapter'] = DB_ADAPTER;
$propelConfig['datasources']['rp']['connection'] = $dsnRp;
$propelConfig['datasources']['rp']['adapter'] = DB_ADAPTER;
//$propelConfig['datasources']['dbarray']['connection'] = 'dbarray://user:pass@localhost/pm_os';
//$propelConfig['datasources']['dbarray']['adapter']    = 'dbarray';

Propel::initConfiguration($propelConfig);

// enable rbac
Bootstrap::LoadSystem('rbac');
$RBAC = &RBAC::getSingleton(PATH_DATA, session_id());
$RBAC->sSystem = 'PROCESSMAKER';

spl_autoload_register(
   function($class) {

      static $classes = null;
      if ($classes === null) {
          $classes = array(
              'MyNameSpace\ClassName' => 'classes/class.MyPluginName.php',
          );
      }
      $cn = strtolower($class);
      if (isset($classes[$cn])) {
        if( ! class_exists($cn, false) && ! interface_exists($cn, false) )
            //echo PATH_PLUGINS . PLUGIN_NAME . PATH_SEP . $classes[$cn];
          require PATH_PLUGINS . PLUGIN_NAME . PATH_SEP . $classes[$cn];
      }
   }
);
```

Comment: Basically, the phpunit.xml tells phpunit where the bootstrap file is, which the bootstrap file loads up the entire ProcessMaker environment and also instantiates your classes (at the bottom of it). The phpunit.xml also allows you to configure and define the constants that ProcessMaker needs to be defined which are normally passed through an http call, like language and workspace etc

I have tested this and it works for all ProcessMaker 3.x versions.